# Size of conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we are given |$D_{10}$|, why can the conjugacy classes only have size 1,2, or 5? Why not 10?

I know that the size of conjugacy classes divides |$G$|

Answer (score 1):

The conjugacy classes partition the group, and the identity element is the only member of its conjugacy class. Thus, no conjugacy class can be the whole group: all must be smaller, and size $10$ is therefore impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Brian M. Scott 
How do we know that the identity element is the only member of its conjugacy class though?

Comment: @kelly: Because $g1_Gg^{-1}=1_G$ for every $g\in G$: the only thing conjugate to the identity is itself.